# Sorting both ID and 2 sets of values using STL containers

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, data-structures, stl

I need suggestion to use STL containers in the best possible way to sort  3 sets of data
1. A ID (Integer)
2. First Value (String)
3. Second Value (String)

An example of the data structure is as below:

[image]

I want to use map as it is sorted at the time of insert and no need to execute a sorting algorithm separately. Since the ID can repeat it must be a multimap, and each data of a column is linked to each other so the rows will change in order to sort keeping the same values attached to a ID.

Sorting the ID and value is ok, but how do I sort 2 values as multimap can take only one value. From my thinking it will be multimap of a multimap or a struct of the data structure and then STL containers. But I want to make it as simple as possible. I need suggestion on how this can be achieved.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the "sorted at time of insertion" comment suggest you will set this up once, then just walk over it - no further inserts or deletes?

Comment: Not eactly! I want to auto sort on each insert and delete and not execute sort after each operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a map or a set makes sense if and only if you are going to do many insert/erase operations it. If the data structure is static, storing a vector and sorting it once is way more effective. That said, if I understand your question correctly, I think you don't need a map, but a multiset.

```
typedef pair<int, pair<string, string>> myDataType;

set<myDataType> mySet;
```

here, the `operator <` of pair will take care of the ordering.

If you don't want to refer to the id as `elem.first`, and to the strings as `elem.second.first`, and `elem.second.second`, then you can use a struct and overload `operator <` for it.

```
struct myType
{ 
     int id;
     string s1;
     string s2;   
};
bool operator < (const myType& t1, const myType& t2)
{
    return make_tuple(t1.id, t1.s1, t1.s2) < make_tuple(t2.id, t2.s1, t2.s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `std::set<std::tuple<int, std::string, std::string>>`. Tuples are lexicographically compared thus you would get the effect you want for free.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/901c0fd80b443005)

Answer (score 0):

Elements in a multimap are sorted by the Key. You cannot 'sort' multimap. What you can do is to create vector of `pairs<Key, Map<Key>::Interator>` with elements fulfilling some logical condition and sort vector.

Comment: Check your formatting. Look at the post preview before hitting submit, and double-check the results after your answer has been posted.